# Simple Injector Still Works without Registration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, simple-injector

I'm a little confused here why my code using Simple Injector still works perfectly even with no registration and would appreciate it if someone could provide some insight.

Basically, I have a typical 3 logical tiers architecture, Web API controller, business service layer, and data access service layer. My Web API project has a reference to the business service project, which in addition to business service classes it also has the .edmx and generated entity classes.

My Web API controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly BookService bkService;

    public MyController(BookService bk)
    {
        bkService = bk;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetBooks")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBooks()
    {
        var books = bkService.GetBooks();
        var ret = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(books);
        return Ok(ret);
    }
}
```

The business service is:

```
public class BookService : AbstractService
{
    public BookService(MyContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        var da = new Da(ContextContainer);
        return da.SelectAll<Book>();
    }
}
```

Here's what I have in Startup.cs (I'm using Owin for the Web API):

```
HttpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
HttpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(HttpConfiguration);
container.Verify();

HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

app.UseWebApi(HttpConfiguration);
```

As you can see, I have no registration in Startup.cs; however, the code still works perfectly.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the auto-wiring feature of Simple Injector. This is described here: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#automatic-constructor-injection-auto-wiring

Comment: @Ric.NetAh, that's it! I totally missed that. It also says "Even though Simple Injector can create a concrete type even if it hasn’t been registered explicitly in the container, best practice is to register all types explicitly in the container." I wonder why it's better to register all types explicitly.

Comment: "I wonder why it's better to register all types explicitly." That is explained [here](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#verify-configuration).